# How to change query limit based on query conditions?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Is there a way to change the limit for query dynamically based on the query itself?

In particular my task is to query all unread notifications or last three notifications (in whatever state they are). In other words, I need no limit in the first case, and I need a limit of 3 in the second case.

A notification "schema" looks like the following.

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("..."),
  "text": "You've got a new message",
  "flags": [
    { user: ObjectId("..."), flag: "seen" }
  ]
}
```

I am using mongoose if it makes any sense.

Comment: Tag about "unread" is unseen. So is `notification` an element of array in document? If true, full schema for top document is helpful to resolve the question.

Comment: @Wizard: `notification` is a top-level document in a collection.

Comment: No. Just use two queries, the second of which only needs to execute if there are no unread queries.